# Troubleshooting Ajax Post Filter in WordPress - Not responding to WP_Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've created an Ajax post filter for a blog. When you click a category to filter the posts below, what happens is odd. The markup of the current page is injected rather than the results of my WP_Query arguments. So you end up with the page nested within itself.

Here's my post filter bar with the initial query populating the response div:

[image]

Here's the form:

```html
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="POST" id="filter">
  <label><input type="radio" name="category" value="" checked="checked"><div>All</div></label>
  <!-- Loop Selected Categories -->
  <label><input type="radio" name="category" value="Category_ID"><div>Category Name</div></label>
  <!-- End Loop Selected Categories -->

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

Below is my JavaScript:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            success:function(data){
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
    });
    console.log('form submitted');
        return false;
  });

  $('#filter input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $("#filter").submit();
  });
});
```

Below the filter form there's a response div that contains the initial/default query results:

```php
<div class="post-grid" id="response">
    <?php
       $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_status' => array('publish')
      );
      $query = new WP_Query( $args );

      if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
          return get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-card' );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
      else :
        echo 'No posts found';
      endif;
    ?>
  </div>
```

I have the following code to query the selected category in my functions.php:

```php
// In my enqueued scripts
wp_enqueue_script( 'post_filter_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/post-filter.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
wp_localize_script( 'post_filter_js', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


// Function to query the selected category
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'filter_post_by_cat');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'filter_post_by_cat');

function filter_post_by_cat(){  
    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['category'] ) ):
        $args = array(
            'category__in' => $_POST['category'], 
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => array('publish')
        );
    endif;

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            echo get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-card' );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>`  in the inspector?

Comment: @RichardMiles
http://mighty-moms-2019.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Are you sure "ajax_object.ajaxurl" contains the correct path to WP-ajax?

Comment: @ninja - There was a typo: it should be `ajax_object.ajax_url` not `ajax_object.ajaxurl`. So I was missing an underscore and that is the correct path to the admin-ajax.php file.

But even after fixing that I have the same result of the current page's content being injected into the response div rather than my WP_Query results.

Comment: Getting the whole page as response from the ajax-request is usually what happens when nothing is returned from the call. Usually when I have this problem it's the ajax url that is wrong, hence why I asked about it :)

I would error_log in your PHP-function to make sure the function gets called properly. And maybe check that the return'd data from the PHP function actually returns something :)

Comment: So, I don't understand how this works exactly, but I followed another example of using Ajax in WordPress and the developer added `+ '&action=myfilter'` where I only had `data: $(this).serialize()`. So total the fix was `data: $(this).serialize() + '&action=myfilter'`. I suppose my WP_Query function wasn't being called without that action.